# Android GPS data is not displayed

Tags: android, gps

I am new to android development. In the last months I built an app that is now working. Now I want to improve all the small things that bother me every time I open the app.

In this case, I try to get the GPS(only GPS) position. Whenever a position update comes in, it should be displayed.

For any reason, the first positions (I can see them coming in in the debug log) are ignored and not displayed on my device.

Here is the code:

```
public class GpsLogging extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps_logging);

    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        double lat = loc.getLatitude();
        double lon = loc.getLongitude();
        float accuracy = loc.getAccuracy();

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gpsPosition);
        textView.setText("My current location is: \n" +
                "Latitude = " + lat +"\n"+
                "Longitude = " + lon +"\n"+
                "Accuracy = " + accuracy +" m");

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}
```

Would be nice, if someone have an idea why the unprecise data is ignored.

Here is the corresponding xml as requested:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.example.GpsLogging">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gpsPosition"
    android:text="Aquiring GPS Position"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: post layout xml also...

Comment: Your device have GPS activated? Check

Comment: "I can see them coming in in the debug log" :- where you wrote the printing statement for logs.

Answer (score 0):

use the

```
 .getLastKnownLocation()
```

method.

example:

```
Location earlierLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

reason: you just print on onLocationChanged (new gps).

Comment: Thanks for that.
I thought the incoming data is always an updated location.

inline 'source: 2
    latitude: 53.072959
    longitude: 8.793933
    altitude: 181.399994
    speed: 0.000000
    bearing: 0.000000
    accuracy: 7.000000
    timestamp: 1446805781000
    rawDataSize: 0
    rawData: 0x0
    Session status: 0
    Technology mask: 1'

Comment: @Entropia Fine. Then you can accept my answer. Cheers